# 516808 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c

Tags: pyinstaller

I run executable, but I keep getting error:

> 516808 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
>   dependency of c

How do I suppress these error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually get the same, and this is due to pyinstaller 32 bit python.  Not to fear they are harmless

Read this related issue on [github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566), if you're more interested but those errors should not break functionality ;).  Correct me if I'm wrong though, but I've never found it affects exe's

Comment: Try it on a new pc

Answer (score 0):

you should download and install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable to solve this problem.
Good Luck